# Problem with fontspec in MacTex 2016

Tags: xetex, compiling, fontspec, latexian

I'm having a problem compiling documents using the `fontspec` package after updating to MacTex 2016. Specifically, if I include

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

in my document preamble, compiling fails in Latexian and is successful in TexShop without any custom fonts.

A minimum working example that fails:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[10.5pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{hanging} 
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \mmddyyyydate


% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

Hello!

\end{document}
```

In contrast, this compiles fine:

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[10.5pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,usenames]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{xltxtra,fontspec} 
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{hanging} 
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{lmodern}
 \mmddyyyydate


% DOCUMENT
\begin{document}

Hello!

\end{document}
```

Any idea what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Strange. It works fine for me. Did you install MacTeX new, or upgrade from 2015?

Comment: Welcome! How does it fail? Do you get an error? If so, what is the exact text of that error? Latexian is probably not as good at figuring out MacTeX's peculiarities automatically, so check the settings (especially path settings) for Latexian and compare with those for TeXShop.

Comment: Incidentally, it almost certainly makes no sense to load `fontenc` or `lmodern` if using XeTeX and `fontspec`.

Comment: You need to make sure that the path is set correctly in LaTeXian. It should be set to `/Library/TeX/texbin` not `/usr/texbin`. In addition to @cfr 's comment, there is no such thing as `10.5pt` as an option to the `article` class (10, 11, and 12 are the only choices).

Comment: The default font used when loading go spec already is Latin Modern. One usually loads fontspec so they can use system fonts.

Comment: This is the error I get in LaTexian: 
! 
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX.
! 
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or
! "lualatex"instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................  
                                                  
￼l.28 \msg_fatal:nn {fontspec} {cannot-use-pdftex}
                                                 
 ) )

Comment: Additionally, TeXShop has the same error as in LaTexian

Comment: Like the error says, you need to use XeTeX or LuaTeX, not pdfTeX, here.